# How to disable welcome screen in Intellij Idea 2021

Tags: intellij-idea

Someone can help me to disable this **welcome screen** because I need sometimes to open 2-3 projects at the same time. previous version I didn't get this experience.

I tried below way but It didn't work for me.
File> System Settings> project>

[image]

Comment: What is expected behavior for you? What do you want to be opened?

Comment: In previous version, open all projects in same time without coming a welcome screen.